# Is it possible to apply CDC's on a parquet file?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, avro, parquet, aws-glue

I'm using spark and need to apply cdc files from a database replica on a parquet file, like an upsert.
I already did the code to get the last state of each ID in the Cdc file but now I need to apply these last states on the historical parquet.

Comment: Can't you CDC into Kafka and then use Spark to write it into Parquet in append mode?

Comment: Hello Felipe, sorry, I wasn't very clear on the question but what I'd like was to merge the parquet file, not to append. I'm expecting to resolve that with delta lake features when they release the merge and update feature.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not - see this JIRA - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PARQUET-1289

ORC files have this capability (used to enable ACID compliance in Hive) but I'm not sure how you would access that capability from Spark. https://orc.apache.org/docs/acid.html